# Arduino 75kHz output frequency setup

Tags: pwm, frequency

i don't know how to manipulate arduino uno or mega registers and timers to be close to 75kHz output frequency. Could you help please ?

Comment: output frequency from where to where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to compute, from your desired frequency, the number of
CPU cycles per period of the signal:

F_CPU / 75 kHz = 16,000 kHz / 75 kHz ≈ 213.33

Since the timers can only count up to an integer, the closest you can
get is 213 CPU cycles. The frequency you get will then be

F_CPU / 213 = 16,000 kHz / 213 ≈ 75.12 kHz

Now you can configure a timer. I find that the easiest is to use a so
called “fast PWM” mode. Choose one of those modes where the TOP value
can be set with a register, and set it to one unit less than the desired
period: the timer will then repeatedly count from 0 to 212.

Here is an example using channel A of Timer 1 on an Arduino Uno.
The output is on digital pin 9 = OC1A = PB1:

```cpp
// Configure Timer 1 for PWM @ 75.12 kHz.
DDRB  |= PB1;         // set OC1A = PB1 as output
TCCR1A = 0;           // clear the settings of the Arduino core
TCCR1B = 0;           // ...ditto
TCNT1  = 0;           // clear the timer
TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1)  // non-inverting PWM on OC1A
       | _BV(WGM11);  // mode 14: fast PWM, TOP = ICR1
TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12)   // ...ditto
       | _BV(WGM13)   // ...ditto
       | _BV(CS10);   // clock at F_CPU
ICR1   = 213 - 1;     // period = 213 CPU cycles = 13.3125 us
OCR1A  = 213/2 - 1;   // duty cycle ~ 50%
```

You can easily adapt this to any timer on the Uno or Mega. Just avoid
Timer 0 if you are going to use the Arduino timekeeping functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer given by Edgar Bonet is the right one, all things considered, and I up-voted it for that reason.

For S&G, I want to add the following:

1. The **easiest** way is to simply use the tone(GPIO,Frequency); command - and there are caveats. **BUT**, the frequency argument is an unsigned int so the fastest frequency is 65535Hz - it will do you no good for 75kHz.

Using a frequency counter and an UNO (crystal), tone(10,65535); the output was 65556/8 Hz. On a Pro Mini 5V (ceramic resonator as I recall), it was 65540 Hz.

2. Again, for S&G, I tried this code (and adjusted the number of NOPs) to get as close as I could to 75kHz:

void setup() {
pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
}

```
void loop() {
here:
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(3);
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(3);
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  __asm__("nop\n\t");
  goto here;
}
```

The output on the UNO was 75004/6 Hz  - not too bad. On the Pro Mini, the best I could do was 74986 Hz.

Of course, we are talking about square waves.

Comment: Note that: 1. You can replace `delayMicroseconds()` and the train of `nop` with a single call to [`_delay_us()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html). This macro has single cycle resolution: `_delay_us(3.4375)` delays by exactly 55 CPU cycles with a 16 MHz clock. 2. This approach works better with interrupts disabled. Otherwise you get a small glitch on every timer interrupt. BTW: what does “S&G” mean?

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=S%26G picked up the expression for someplace a long time ago :)